# R dates automatically detected when reading in .csv files?

Tags: r, excel, date, format, read.csv

I have a chunk of code that I regularly run to read in and clean up a.csv file.  Part of the clean up process is to identify date columns and convert them to the correct format, which I do with a function (see below).  I set the date format to convert from to be `"%d/%m/%Y"` as this is how it appears in the .csv file when I view it in MS Excel (office 2010).

```
    > convert.dates
function(data, datestring, excludestring=NULL, extradatecols=NULL, dateformat) {
  if(is.null(extradatecols)) {datecols1 <- grep(datestring, names(data), value=TRUE)} else {datecols1 <- c(grep(datestring, names(data), value=TRUE), extradatecols)}  
  if(is.null(excludestring)) {datecols2 <- datecols1} else {datecols2 <- datecols1[-grep(excludestring, datecols1)]}
  data[, datecols2] = data.frame(lapply(data[, datecols2], as.Date, format=dateformat), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  data
}
```

I recently upgraded to R 3.2.3 and updated my R Studio to version 0.99.489 as well.

After the update, my function failed to convert the dates despite the correct format being selected (based on what I could see in the .csv file).  On further inspection, `read.csv` had converted my dates from the `"%d/%m/%Y"` format that I observed in the .csv file to `"%Y-%m-%d"` and stored them as a factor.  I was then able to apply my convert.dates function with the `"%Y-%m-%d"` format and it worked.

```
> str(mydata$dob)
Factor w/ 3069 levels "1960-01-15" "1977-05-03" "2014-01-19" NA NA  ...

> mydata <- convert.dates(data = gdw, datestring = "date", excludestring = NULL, extradatecols = c("dob"), dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d")

> str(mydata$dob)
Date[1:5000], format: "1960-01-15" "1977-05-03" "2014-01-19" NA NA  ...
```

This is not a big deal if that is now the expected behaviour of read.csv, but I couldn't find anything about this in the release notes, so just wanted to check - is read.csv supposed to identify anything in `%d/%m/%Y` format and convert it to `%Y-%m-%d` when reading in, or is this something to do with MS Excel automatically converting the display of dates when viewing a .csv file (although the way they are actually written could be different)?  The .csv file is a download from a postgres database.  I'm not sure what the usual format of dates in the original database is.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have seen weird stuff with MS Excel. I was working with a colleague on the same csv file and we had different date format because we were using different version of MS Excel....

Comment: It was BOTH converting dates, and then turning them into factors? That doesn't seem right at all. I could see converting them...but factors? As for converting, the way something appears in Excel when you view a CSV isn't always the way it's stored. Can you examine the file with a text editor and confirm that the dates are `%d/%m/%Y`?

Comment: I've had luck opening CSV's in a text editor to get a better idea of how they are storing dates

Comment: @TARehman, yes it seemed strange to me too to to go to all the trouble of converting the dates to the correct format, then storing them as factors.  I have since checked with the person who manages the postgres database and it turns out the dates are stored in "%Y-%m-%d" format, so the issue is MS excel falsely representing the dates when I open the .csv file.

Comment: If there is a thing I learned the hard way in my experience, it is to never ever open a csv file with Excel.